# How to install a cross-compiler for the Pi on OSX

Tags: operating-systems, cross-compilation

I recently started the course from Cambridge University on writing your own OS, but i´m having some trouble. Here is my question:

1. I have tried to install the yagarto tool, but i didnt succed.
2. I have tried to compile with the Xcode but i get errors regarding sintaxis (which is what makes me think that i am not using a compiler for armv6)
3. Is there any way to compile armv6 in a MAC?

Comment: You definitely cannot use the regular Xcode compiler.  There *might* be an added complication here in that you want to compile for bare metal; I'm not sure.  Hopefully someone comes along with the details.  You also might want to consider going into detail on how you "didn't succeed" with the yagarto tool, there may be a simple solution to that.

Comment: Don't forget ;\ [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#intro). You have a steep road ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of problems when trying to compile kernel on MacOSX so I resorted to virtual machine with Linux installed.